# Making an overlay with vulkan

Tags: overlay, vulkan

I've done some work with Vulkan and understand that I need to make a `VkSurfaceKHR` in order to render to. Does anyone know of a way I can get an overlay surface to draw on when games are running so that I could make something like the steam fps counter or fraps?

Comment: I don't believe it does, no

Comment: Well, I would make an identical answer here. What's missing?

Comment: I believe that Vulkans layer API would help me build an overlay, but only for use in Vulkan applications. I would like to be able to use my overlay in DX/GL applications as well. I thought windows must provide an API for this because Steam, Discord and FRAPS all have overlays.

Comment: It is easier said than done, hence why I suggested an open-source premade solution. Vulkan provides the Layering. Windows provides similar technique called Hooks, which can intercept system calls (including Dx stuff). And I believe you can intercept OpenGL calls with the same (basic wgl and getprocaddr are system calls), otherwise it typically uses GDI+ which could be intercepted. Then of course Linux would also be different, and might further differ for X and Wayland.

Comment: so you're saying that there is no easy way to write overlay software that will work for Vulkan, GL and D3D? you have to write hooks for each API? this is unfortunate

Comment: Yes, only the hard way. The only easy way is not to reinvent the wheel and use pre-existing solution.

Comment: Which pre-existing solutions should I have a look at?

Comment: I only know the OCAT from top of my head. Does not support OGL I think